# Pairing JSON values from nested groups in JS

Tags: javascript, json

I am learning JSON and JavaScript and so far I am able to read the simple values. However, I do not know how to obtain lower level data pairs, such as in:

```
{ statusCode: 200,
content: '{"X":{"key":"k","name":"n", "nested":[{"nestedValue":"A","value":"111"},{"nestedValue":"B","value":"222"},{"nestedValue":"3","value":"333","bestValue":false}]}}',
 headers: {.....
```

I tried simple iterating but that does not work. I would like to get pairs such as A:111 and B:222.

Answer (score 1):

```js
let content = {
  "X": {
    "key": "k",
    "name": "n",
    "nested": [{
      "nestedValue": "A",
      "value": "111"
    }, {
      "nestedValue": "B",
      "value": "222"
    }, {
      "nestedValue": "3",
      "value": "333",
      "bestValue": false
    }]
  }
};

let arr = content.X.nested;
Object.entries(arr).forEach((entry) => {
  console.log(entry[0] + ' - ' + entry[1]);
  Object.entries(entry[1]).forEach(([key, val]) => {
    console.log(key + ' / ' + val);
  })
})

console.log(content.X); //obj
console.log(content.X.key); //value
console.log(content.X.nested); //array
console.log(content.X.nested[0].nestedValue); //value
console.log(content.X.nested[1].value); //value
```

I left the different console.log for you to see

Comment: Thanks, I'm trying what you described - I can get the "content", but "context.X" returns undefined.

Comment: EDIT: content.X or any other elements are just not accessible for some reason, always returning Undefined.

Comment: I've edited the snippet and added several console.log with ways to access datas at several level. Here you have an object, inside this object you have an array, and inside array item you have object

Comment: Thanks, but when trying with my JSON, content.X always returns Undefined, I have no idea why I can access the content but not the underlying ones. I will update the question with the full JSON, I though the other parts do not matter.

Comment: I noticed that before the {X, there is the ' in the response, seems the whole content is within ' '. I assume this is the problem? It is in my snippet.

Comment: yes can you update with your real full json, otherwise I can't help!